# How to put @font-face with external link?

Tags: css

when i searched the way to put @font-face in css
people used to put like this:

```
@font-face{
    font-family:"Testfont";
    src:url("Fonts/5876/example.woff2") format("woff2"),
        url("Fonts/5876/example.woff") format("woff");
}
```

because in there folder there has index.html file
so they made font file in there

[image]

my problem is i made my website form using some other site.
like shopify,

so i don't have index file, and can't even access that folder which have index.html file

in this situation, i can't make "font" folder and can't put the font in there.
so i tried use font-face using external link
like this:

```
@font-face{
    font-family:"Brewery W05 Bold";
    src:url("http://mysite.img13.kr/site/Fonts/5119972/example.woff2") format("woff2"),
        url("http://mysite.img13.kr/site/Fonts/5119972/example.woff") format("woff");
}
```

i put font file to other ftp system, and bring the link and put that code in there.
but not working....
am i miss anything?

any help will be so appreciated
thanks :)

Comment: Are you using Shopify? or something else? Usually they have a way for you to edit the theme so you can customize it by adding custom CSS

Comment: @sagar1025 hi! thanks for your help, and Shopify is an example. MakeShop is what i used to make my site. i can change the font if i use other font what they provide but, the font that i want to use is not of their option so that's why i try to put it by using css and font-face code in css;; is there any way to fix this problem? or am i miss anything in code?

Comment: If the font you want is available on Google Fonts, you can just use something like
`<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Antonio:wght@100&family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap');
</style> `
If the font is not available you'll have to host the font somewhere with something like TypeKit
https://helpx.adobe.com/fonts/user-guide.html/fonts/using/add-fonts-website.ug.html